# Ionic2 - element._view is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, typescript2.0

I try implements chart.js into ionic project,, i take values from firebase.. i push datas using subscribe.. here is my code

```
export class HomePage {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  itemsChart: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  listArray: any[] = [];

  public lineChartType:string = 'line';
  public lineChartData:Array<any> = [{data: [], label: 'Grafik'}];
  public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, af: AngularFire) {
    this.itemsChart = af.database.list('/kelembaban', {
       preserveSnapshot : true,
       query: {
         orderByKey: true,
         limitToLast: 10
       }
    }).map((array) => array.reverse()) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

    this.itemsChart.subscribe(snapshots => {
      snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
        this.lineChartLabels.push(snapshot.val().time);
        console.log(this.lineChartLabels);
        this.lineChartData[0]['data'].push(snapshot.val().value);
        console.log(this.lineChartData[0]['data']);
      });
    });
   }
}
```

i dont know whats wrong with my code.. ty for advice

Comment: Is there a problem somewhere? I think you forgot to state that :)

Comment: @AJT_82 what that bro?

Comment: I mean is there a problem somewhere? That's unclear? Code not working apparently, which part isn't working? :)

Comment: interface can display in a few second then, it come error,, [here](http://imageshack.com/a/img924/8959/92Lsx7.png)